# Is there a way to get the resulting Makefile after includes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a (GNU) Makefile, one can do:

```
include foo.mk

all:
    @echo "Hello, world!"
```

Is there a way to get make to spit out the Makefile after foo.mk has been included? Akin to after the C preprocessor has expanded macros etc.?

Update: a commenter below asked me to specify which problem I'm trying to solve. I wish to trigger a rebuild when/if there's changes to the Makefile and/or the underlying, included makefiles. I've found a recipe that goes something like:

```
.PHONY: bar

SHAFILE := foobar.sha256
$(SHAFILE): bar
    @sha256sum Makefile | cmp -s - $@ || sha256sum Makefile > $@

...

%.o: %.c $(SHAFILE)
$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

(Obviously, the checksum should be of the Makefile including includes, but this is a start.)

Comment: I'm not convinced that you get what you want, with `%.o` depends on `$(SHAFILE)` depends on (phony).  A better question would be *"How do I make all my targets depend on the (effective) Makefile?"* (with a body that explains that the "effective Makefile" takes account of the transitive includes).  What you'd really like would be a variable like `$(ALL_MAKEFILES)` that your targets could depend on.

Comment: In fact, I think that `$(MAKEFILE_LIST)` might be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: MAKEFILE_LIST is very interesting indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: I haven't tried this, only read the manual.

After all your `include` lines (including the transitive set of nested includes, and even lines created by text substitution or built by functions), the Make variable `MAKEFILE_LIST` will reference all your makefiles.

So it should be sufficient to add a dependency to the end of your file such as

```
%.o: $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
```

You don't actually need the contents of the effective Makefile, just the list of files that comprise it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get make to spit out the Makefile after foo.mk has been included?

No.

There's `gmake -d` with a ton of debug output, some of which indicating which makefiles are being read:

```
$ gmake -d|grep Reading
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `GNUmakefile'...
Reading makefile `foo.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
```

This might be helpful if there are recursive include directives or those under conditionals.

Maybe you could tell us your actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated the original question.